# Url of dynamic component

Tags: broker, dynamic-publishing

Is it possible to get the URL of pages where a dynamic component has been used, i.e. to resolve a URL at run time of a dynamic component.

Here is the exact scenario which I am referring to in my solution.
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7803/2948

**Detailed Question:** A schema with a dynamic component templates i.e. CT(Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly), I want to generate a list of such dynamic component with a url redirecting user to its detail page(with static CT).

**Progress Till now:** Created a list of dynamic component, but without URL.

**Need to have a way where user can go to the detailed page where a particular dynamic component has been used**

Comment: Have you tried using CD Linking APIs to resolve the Component IDs to Page URLs?

Answer (score 1):

For those having similar issue:

```
using Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration; //namespace for SiteConfiguration
string UrlOfDynamicComponent=string.Empty;
try
{
string TCMURI= "tcm:" + WebRequestContext.Localization.LocalizationId + "-" + ComponentURI;
UrlOfDynamicComponent = SiteConfiguration.LinkResolver.ResolveLink(TCMURI); 
}
catch
{
UrlOfDynamicComponent =string.Empty;
}
```

The string returned will be a url(if found any) or a null string.